# GraphUnion in Mathematica 12 vs 13

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In Mathematica 13,

```
GraphUnion[g]
```

returns `g`.

In Mathematica 12, in what I can only think is a bug, the same code returns

```
GraphUnion[g]
```

What's the best way to write code that works in both?

(In my code, I actually use `Apply`, but the list of arguments may have only one element.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write code that works correctly in versions from before and after this bug was fixed, use a lightweight wrapper function:

```
myGraphUnion[g_] := g
myGraphUnion[g__] := GraphUnion[g]
```